# Stopping a jquery-ui addClass animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a basic jQuery-ui `addClass` / `removeClass` animation.  I'm running into the classic jQuery issue where I can't properly stop the animation (and so you can get it to repeat again and again by mousing on/off the element).

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8HDnB/2/

If this were via `.animate()` the problem is solved by adding `.stop()` before the `.animate()` calls.  Anyone have any idea how to fix this in this case?

Comment: It's probably just an issue with incompatible versions of jquery & jqueryui.  You'll note that the jsfiddle I posted is a _little_ broken in that the first hover doesn't animate.  The demo works fine "as expected" with updated versions of both (that is it always animates, not that the issue I posted is solved)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$( 'div' ).hover( function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hover') ) {
        $this.addClass( 'hover', 500 );
    }
}, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('hover') ) {
        $this.removeClass( 'hover', 500 );
    }
});
```

This seemed to work for me when I was dealing with `.effect()` used on an element. Just added a class in the beginning of the effect and when the effect finished, I did `.removeClass()`. Then checked whether the element `.hasClass()` or not. May be you've tried this already, I don't know, cause it seems like a quite obvious solution (if that's the solution you are actually looking for).